# How to make my R SVM output to display the predicted class type instead of the actual numerical value?

Tags: r, classification, svm

I am doing SVM on R, and when I do:

```
library(ISLR)
library(e1071)

fit2 = svm(satisfied~PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4, data=data.frame(train.incl.score.x.y.st), kernel="radial", cost=5, gamma=500)

pred2=predict(fit2, data.frame(val.incl.score[,1:4]),  probability=FALSE)

table(pred2, data.frame(val.incl.score.x.y.st)$satisfied)

>> pred2.                  0 1
  -8.37175892132423        1 0
  -7.98589263979825        1 0
  -6.74777840420131        1 0
  -6.70935986153772        1 0
  -6.46316720580385        1 0
  -6.04268844390794        1 0

 <list goes on...>
```

What I want is I want the column pred2 in the output above to display the predicted class type instead of the numerical value that the SVM model assigns to each observation. How can I get the predicted class type for each validation observation, and make confusion matrix accordingly?

Thank you,

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve].  It makes it a lot easier to help you.  Also, which package are you using for `svm`?

Comment: Hello, I am using the packages ISLR and e1071. I will edit my question

Comment: Please provide an example data set that reproduces your problem.  The `svm()` `predict` method _does_ return class labels.  Your method for generating a confusion matrix is correct, and if you try this with toy data (just use "A" and "B" for classes and fit to random data), you'll see you get the confusion matrix you're expecting.  It seems in your case you have continuous values that are getting included in your table somehow.  But it's hard to know what's going on without a [mcve].

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error using the same code with the example dataset iris.. So please do dput(head(val.incl.score.x.y.st)), and paste the output.. Might be that your response is not a factor